# Java Graphics2D drawString is "blacking out" the source image

Tags: java, awt, bufferedimage, graphics2d, javax.imageio

Java 8 and Mac OS (High Sierra) here. I have the following class `TextOverlayer` that reads an image off the file system and needs to overlay some red text onto the image, and then save that "overlayed" image as a different file on the file system:

```java
public class TextOverlayer implements ImageObserver {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      // Instantiate a TextOverlayer and read a source/input image from disk
      TextOverlayer textOverlayer = new TextOverlayer();
      BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(Paths.get("/User/myuser/pix/sourceImage.jpg").toFile());

      // Lay some text over the image at specific coordinates
      BufferedImage drawn = textOverlayer.drawText(bufferedImage, "Some text");

      // Write the overlayed image to disk
      File outputfile = new File("/User/myuser/pix/targetImage.jpg");
      ImageIO.write(drawn, "jpg", outputfile);

  }

  private BufferedImage drawText(BufferedImage old, String text) {

      int w = old.getWidth() / 3;
      int h = old.getHeight() / 3;
      BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(
              w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
      g2d.drawImage(old, 0, 0, w, h, this);
      g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
      g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
      FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
      int x = img.getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text) - 5;
      int y = fm.getHeight();
      g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
      g2d.dispose();

      return img;

  }

  @Override
  public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
      return false;
  }

}
```

When this runs, no errors are thrown and the `targetImage.jpg` is successfully written to disk, except its just an image of a small black box. I would have expected `targetImage.jpg` to be the exact same as `sourceImage.jpg`, just with some extra text added to it at the desired coordinates (within the image).

**Any ideas where I'm going awry?**

Comment: Try using `setColor` instead of `setPaint`

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer (+1) but that does not work either and has the exact same effect.

Comment: I edited the question to show that I am using a Mac and not Linux (I didn't think it would matter...but it might).

Comment: Why are you using TYPE_INT_ARGB?  You might want to try TYPE_INT_RGB.

Comment: Why are you dividing the width and height by 3?  Are you thinking 3 bytes per pixel?  That encoding doesn't affect the width and height of the image.

Comment: You don't need the ImageObserver.  ImageIO is not asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the ImageObserver and you likely can't write an image with an alpha channel to a JPEG file with the included writers.

This works:

```
public class TextOverlayer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Instantiate a TextOverlayer and read a source/input image from disk
        TextOverlayer textOverlayer = new TextOverlayer();
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(Paths.get("/User/myuser/pix/sourceImage.jpg").toFile());

        // Lay some text over the image at specific coordinates
        BufferedImage drawn = textOverlayer.drawText(bufferedImage, "Some text");

        // Write the overlayed image to disk
        File outputfile = new File("/User/myuser/pix/targetImage.jpg");
        boolean result = ImageIO.write(drawn, "jpg", outputfile);
        if (!result) {
            System.out.println("FAILED");
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage drawText(BufferedImage old, String text) {

        int w = old.getWidth();
        int h = old.getHeight();
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.drawImage(old, 0, 0, w, h, null);
        g2d.setPaint(Color.red);
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 20));
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        int x = img.getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(text) - 5;
        int y = fm.getHeight();
        g2d.drawString(text, x, y);
        g2d.dispose();

        return img;

    }
}
```